# Index an object based on the name of the variable

Tags: angular, typescript

For the following object:

```
let key!:myType;

let dict:any = {key : 'value'};
```

Would it be possible to index this `dict` using the name of `key`:

```
dict(nameof(key)) // returns 'value'
```

The reason I want this because I want to check if certain `SimpleChanges` have happened in my Angular component. However, I only want to trigger certain methods if one of the `@Input` vars of my component is changed. However, I'd rather not hardcode the string name.

Indexing it using the variable does not seem to be work as I have assigned it a specific type.

Comment: Are you looking for: `dict[key]` ?

Comment: can you add add your `myType`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is JavaScript (as the question tags imply), then you can index an object with a variable like so:

```
object[variableName]
```

In your  case, something like:

```
dict[key]
```

You may find more help on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

**Edit - Question is now TypeScript**

In this case, you could set the type of the dict object:

```
let key: myType = '';
let dict: {[key: myType]: string} = {key: value};
```

You can see more about [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) here.

Comment: I have updated it to typescript specific. Indexing it using the variable does not seem to be work as I have assigned it a specific type

Comment: I've updated the answer for typescript, see above

Comment: hmm, sorry. I tried to make the question very general. However, by doing this I steered you in the wrong direction. I will reupdate my question,... thx for the ffort though